# Is there a chess move history app for Mac?

Tags: analysis, database

I would like to check various positions to see if I have reached them in the past. I play on lichess.org which lets you download your complete game history as a pgn. I was wondering if anyone knew of a program (or maybe site) that runs on Mac OSX that lets you check position history and shows how many times you have reached that position (and maybe shows what moves you played next).

I have ChessBase on Windows but was looking for a Mac alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the [Scid vs PC](http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/) and [Xboard](https://www.gnu.org/software/xboard/) would do the job. They can both run on Mac.

Comment: I was using [chessx](http://chessx.sourceforge.net/node/3) all along and just realized they have search. Those programs look good too though.